# android studio: copy the key for generate a signed bundle from one computer to another

Tags: android, bundle, signed

With android studio I have created some key something.jks to generate signed bundle. It works pretty good on the computer where the key was created. But now I want to use it on another computer. I tried just copy the file something.jks to the new computer but this doesn't works.  How to proceed ?

Comment: What is not working? All you have to do is enter alias name and password while generating a signed app.

Comment: I have to provide the key store path (that's ok), the key store password, the alias, and the key password, right ? Maybe I am a bit confused with these three things. What should be the alias ? key0 or something as myname.com ?